# Passing variables to #include through #define

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Is it possible to do something along these lines:

```
#define import_and_other(s)\
something\
#include s
```

Such that:

```
import_and_other("file.h")
```

becomes:

```
something
#include "file.h"
```

Basically, there are certain files that always need the same action taken before they are included, so I want to wrap up #include to perform these actions.

Comment: Why do you always need to do the same thing before each `import_and_other` included file?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answers, I have found a different way to do this. For the curious, I am already abusing the preprocessor because it is being used to concatenate and operate on JS files. The hope was to be able to wrap the included files in a function literal:

function() {
the_file
}();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No!

The C99 standard says (section 6.10.2):

> A preprocessing directive of the form
>
> ```
> # include pp-tokens new-line
> ```
>
> (that does not match one of the two previous forms) is permitted. The preprocessing
> tokens after include in the directive are processed just as in normal text. (Each
> identifier currently defined as a macro name is replaced by its replacement list of
> preprocessing tokens.) The directive resulting after all replacements shall match one of
> the two previous forms.

However, there is another rule (section 10.6.3.2, on 'The # Operator') which says:

> Each # preprocessing token in the replacement list for a function-like macro shall be
> followed by a parameter as the next preprocessing token in the replacement list.

The '#include s' in the macro expansion fails this constraint - the word 'include' is not a parameter to the macro-like function.

This prevents you from generating a (usable) '#include' directive.  In any case, during macro expansion, there is another rule (section 10.6.3.4) which says:

> The resulting completely macro-replaced preprocessing token sequence is not processed
> as a preprocessing directive even if it resembles one.

This means that you cannot generate any preprocessor directive from the result of a macro expansion.

Your effort is, sadly, doomed to failure.

Comment: 1) directives can only span one line. 2) directives start it's own respective line. 3) # is the stringizing operator. so failure doomed.

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can make your own include file that does both, and then #include it. Name your header file with the import_and_other name of your choice. The #define replacement text is note REALLY multi-line, it just is wrapped for your benefit.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it. But can achieve the same by including another file and do what ever you want in that file. This will achieve what you are trying to do.